# How to find resource path in maven multimodule application

Tags: java, maven, resources

I have a multimodule maven application that has the following structure:

```
main-project
      ->submodule1
         ->src->main
            ->java
               ->MainClass.java
            ->resource
               ->php
                    index11.php
                    file12.php
                    file13.php
      ->submodule2
         ->src->main
            ->java
               MainClass.java
         ->resource
           ->php
                index21.php
                file22.php
                file23.php
     ->submodule3
        ->src->main
           ->java
               MainClass.java
           ->resource
              ->php
                  index31.php
                  file32.php
                  file33.php
     ->web-app
       ->src->main
            ->webapp
```

Java classes from submodules should access the php files in their resource directories and execute it using Quercus Resin. However, when the project is packed in war, submodules are packed into jar file that are stored in web-app/WEB-INF/lib, which makes it impossible to execute php files. As workaround for this problem, I found solution to copy all php files from the submodules into the web-app, so when it's extracted in Tomcat, it's not inside jar file and could be executed. For that purpose, I'm using maven-remote-resources-plugin, and all php files are stored to web-app/src/main/webapp/php.

The problem I have now is how to properly provide path to these php files from java classes inside submodules.These java classes are inside jar files when application is deployed to Tomcat, but during development I'm using embedded Jetty server, so I need solution that would work in both cases.

If I use class loader to get resource,e.g. **getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/php/index11.php").getPath()** it returns absolute path to the submodule1.jar file.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, so I will post solution here if it might help someone else.

In each submodule I have a maven-remote-resources-plugin bundle to collect all resources I need

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.php</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then, in web-app submodule I'm using maven-remote-resources-plugin process to copy these php files to resource directories called WEB-INF/php/submodule-name

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
      <configuration>
          <resourceBundles>
              <resourceBundle>org.au.morph.offline:morph-sample:${project.version}</resourceBundle>
              <resourceBundle>org.au.morph.offline:morph-project:${project.version}</resourceBundle>
          </resourceBundles>
          <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <goals>
                  <goal>process</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Finally, I created a utility method that resolves the correct path to this directory both when I run application from IDE or in the Tomcat:

```
    public static String getWebContentPath(String contextPath) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String path = PathUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
    String fullPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
    if(fullPath.contains("/WEB-INF/classes")){
        String pathArr[] = fullPath.split("/classes/");
        fullPath=pathArr[0];
    }
    String reponsePath = "";
    reponsePath = new File(fullPath).getPath() + File.separatorChar + "php"+File.separatorChar+contextPath;
    return reponsePath;
}
```